# knockout js polling not working

Tags: json, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am having difficulty with knockout refreshing.

Here's my viewModel;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new Task(), document.getElementById('taskSummary'));
    setInterval(Task, 2000);
});

function task(name, description, project) {
    var self = this;

    self.name= ko.observable(name);
    self.description = ko.observable(description);
    self.project = ko.observable(project);

}


function Task() {
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.tasks.removeAll;
    $.getJSON("/api/tasks/5", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {

            self.tasks.push(new task(val.Name, val.Description, val.Project));

        });
    });

}
```

It returns data to the view but does not update when I change the data in the back end database.

any help appreciated. Im sure its something small that I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

For knockout, it might be better if you apply your model to a new Task instance, save that instance, then set up a setInterval loop that can modify the Task's "tasks" observableArray values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var oTask = new Task();

ko.applyBindings(oTask, document.getElementById('taskSummary'));

function onLoop() {
    var self = oTask;

    $.getJSON("/api/tasks/5", function (data) {
        self.tasks.removeAll(); // not sure if you need this...
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            self.tasks.push(new task(val.Name, val.Description, val.Project));
        });
    });        
}

setInterval(onLoop, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Hi Kirk, Thanks for that. I have tried this code and it doesn't receive any data . . . Will have a play around with it though.

Comment: Panic over - Sorted. Thanks for that Kirk, spot on - much better than my copy and paste skills :)

Comment: My pleasure.  Look for an "accept" button if you think it will also help others with similar issues.